# Sencha Production build throws 4o4 resource not found error while deploying it to Tomcat

Tags: extjs, tomcat7, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I am working on EXTJS6 Application. This application is created and run using sencha cmd. While I work locally, i run the application using sencha cmd without any issues.

I generated the production build and it worked fine I tested it using sencha cmd server but however, while I deployed the production build to the Tomcat/Webapps folder, it throws, resource not found error while hitting the index.html

While hitting below URL
/MyApp/index.html >>

I get this error >>

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://servername.net:36443/MyApp/.js?_dc=20160711183504"
```

I am not sure if I need to make any changes in the app.json or other config files before moving to other servers like Tomcat. Did any one face similar issue?

Comment: Are you running any `dll` in back end for your application. `Dynamic Link Library `

Comment: Can you please elaborate more..sorry

Comment: This is a really weird error. Can you please open Chrome's network tab and provide us with the full list of files that could be downloaded before the error 404 occurred?

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error message (missing file with ".js" filename) it's because you're missing a require for a desired class. You need to make sure that any class you use is included in the "requires" list in the calling class.

Comment: Yeah, But then how it worked well on sencha cmd? I saw this error only while I run my production build on Tomcat